# IconButton onPressed function throws out an error code

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on an app using Flutter. I built an AppBar and a Bottomnavigationbar with IconButtons that should all route to different pages. When I execute though it displays an error message.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Top navigation Bar',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(250, 250, 250, 250),
              elevation: 0,
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                    size: 40.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyLoginPage()),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ]),
          body: Center(
            child: Text('NewsPage'),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyShedulePage()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_ind),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => MyAttendancePage()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on any of the IconButtons, it displays this error message:

> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

Comment: Have you tried passing underscore(_) in MaterialPageRoute instead of context.

Comment: Yes but it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do to remove your bug/error.

**1. Build your BottomNavigationBar in another Stateless Widget:**

```
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget{
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                // MYHomePage is another page for showcase
                // replace it with your page name
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
              );
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
              );
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_ind),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
   }
}
```

And use it for the `bottomNavigationBar` in the `MaterialApp`

```
bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomNavigationBar()
```

**2. Use [Builder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html)** Wrap your bottomNavigationBar items inside your `Builder()`

```
 bottomNavigationBar: Builder(
   builder: (context) => SizedBox(
        height: 60,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
                );
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyShedulePage()),
                );
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_ind),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MyAttendancePage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
       )
      )
```

Here is the Demo for you **using Point number 1 from my answer**, having `MyHomePage()` as another widget to be pushed to from the `MyApp`

[image: DEMO GIF]

**PLEASE NOTE:** You cannot use `Navigator.push` to go from same page to same page. In your code here, you are pushing to `MyApp()`. So please take care of that

```
               // please see here, not a good practise. Make sure
               // page is different, not same
               IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
                    );
                  },
                )
```

Comment: Wonderful @NotTschuschl All the very best :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this (use context for purposes) under Material App widget Try this

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Top navigation Bar',
      home:HomePage()
);

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold( //Your code inside Scaffold..);
}
}
```